# Python timezone conversion

Tags: python, time

I have the following time: `20111122050940.086000` and I would like to convert to seconds, so I'm using the following code:

```
def get_precision_datenum( self, datestring ):
        ymdhms, usec = datestring.split( '.' )

        timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime( ymdhms, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S" )          
        datenum = mktime( timestamp.timetuple() ) + float( usec ) / 1000000
        print datenum;
        return  "%10.3f" % datenum
```

When I'm converting back, from seconds to timetuple then the hour is less with one hour. Example instead of `2011-11-22 05:09:40`, I'm getting `2011-11-22 04:09:40`.

Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: are there always 6 digits after the `.`? If not, the following might be better: `datenum = mktime(timestamp.timetuple()) + float("." + usec)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your datestring is in UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import pytz

datestring = '20111122050940.086000'
ymdhms, usec = datestring.split('.')

dt = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.strptime(ymdhms, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple()) + float(usec) / 1000000.
```

prints `1321938580.086` (independently from your system timezone)

To print it as UTC:

```
dt_utc = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1321938580.086))

# datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 22, 5, 9, 40, 86000, tzinfo=<UTC>)

dt_utc.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')

# '20111122050940.086000'
```

if you are in a different time zone, you have to convert it first:

```
dt_hu = dt_utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Budapest'))

# datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 22, 6, 9, 40, 86000, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Budapest' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

and then print it:

```
dt_hu.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S.%f')

# '20111122060940.086000'
```

This works independently from your system time zone too.

Comment: Is it UTC and my timezone is CET

Comment: To look up Python timezone conversions, I use the handy table from the PyCon 2012 presentation by Taavi Burns.  http://taaviburns.ca/presentations/what_you_need_to_know_about_datetimes/ http://pyvideo.org/video/946/what-you-need-to-know-about-datetimes